# How to create a Python (2.7) regular expression t to find Ascii 06 followed by any two extended ascii characters

Tags: python-2.7, expression

I'm parsing a file using Python 2.7 and I'm trying to find all occurrences of the following pattern

ASCII 06 followed by any two characters in the range from ASCII 0 to ASCII 255

Naive try #1 - [chr(6)][chr(0)-chr(255][chr(0)-chr(255]
  fails with a message that indicates the range cannot be strings.

I've tried several other combos - no success.

The record that I'm parinsg was read in

sF = open('D:\Scratch\xxxxx.01', 'r')
record = sF.read()

Any help will be gratefully appreciated.

Thanx,

Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you're using python2.7, your `open().read()` will return bytes.  You can use the following bytes regex to match ASCII 06 followed by 2 [0-255] bytes:

```
reg = re.compile(b'\x06..')
```

Note that I used `.` here as any byte will satisfy 0 - 255 (except the newline character `\n` (`\xa0`))

If you wanted to also match the newline character you could do one of the following things:

```
# Uses the DOTALL flag to force `.` to match `\n`
reg = re.compile(b'\x06..', re.DOTALL)
# Makes a character class which matches all bytes
reg = re.compile(b'\x06[\x00-\xff]{2}')
```

Comment: Updated with one tiny detail I forgot when I quickly wrote this :)

Comment: Anthony, In fact the '.' is NOT finding ASCII 10 (newline). It's finding everying else as far as I can see..